# kSoap 2 2.6.5 Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject'

Tags: android, ksoap

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
```

I need something new on ksoap 2 so I updated to 2.6.5 but I doesn't work. gave me this error. but Its builds with no exception. I suspect about this one not sure; I have ksoap2 in libs after I add jar It also appear on root (src - gen - android 4.0.3 - ksoap2 - assets bla bla)

thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, to make the solution a bit clear for the next followers:

1. right-click on your project -> *property*
2. select *Java Build Path*
3. tab *order and export* -> check on your jar library file which is KSOAP jar for issue.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is the link you may find this jar file it works for me.

[Click Here](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=)

Comment: The link is broken Now..!!